# What do I put in /etc/fw_env.config when using Debian Jessie's u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin

Tags: debian, u-boot

I'm trying  to move my exsting armhf Debian Jessie setup from a CuBox to a BananaPro. I've copied the u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin from the u-boot-sunxi package to an offset 8k from the start of the sdcard.  I'm now trying to check (and possibly modify) the environment embedded therein.

I tried the fw_env.config values from here:
https://blog.night-shade.org.uk/2014/01/fw_printenv-config-for-allwinner-devices/ but get the CRC error when I run fw_printenv which suggests they are not correct for this version of u-boot.

The file appears to contain something that looks like a u-boot environment at a much lower offset but I don't know enough about the structure of the file to figure out the actual values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote the blogpost you linked. Have you ever booted the system from the uboot you wrote to the SD card?

The reason is that there isn't an environment written to the SD card until you have run saveenv. Until you have run saveenv u-boot will use internal defaults embedded in the u-boot binary.